# How to get all user manager hirarchy in user SOQL ? or any other way?

Tags: user

I have more than 50000 users in org. This is hitting limit now.

I want to get all the user managers

Ex:
   A user
   B is manager for A
   C is manager for B
   and so on..
   There are more than 5 levels
Now I want to get A,B,C,D.. user IDs

I checked with Manager.ID,Manager.Manager.ID but i can;t go more than 5.

Is that possible ? any other workaround. ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Requirement is , I have private object which needs to be shared based on Manger in record owner (the custom setting sharelevel have all share setting level1 -write, level2 - read) .  [select managerID [level1], manager.managerID[level2].. manager.manager.managerID [level3]  from user]